# Pass identity user to services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We are developing a web application in which the user can register orders, customers, etc. and later review them. We have services that are used by MVC controllers in order to interface with the web UI.

Now we face the problem of multiple users: each service should be provided the currently authorised user Id, so all operations (CRUD and bussiness logic) will only be allowed for that user id. How is it supposed to be passed?

I am thinking about having a parameter passed to my `IDataService` (base class for services), which is instantiated by the `WhateverController`, which in turn has access to the `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method, BUT as I am using an IoC container (Ninject) I don't know how to do that. I guess that `IDataService` needs a reference to a `IUserInfoProvider`, so it can call `IUserInfoProvider.GetUserId()`. Then I can inject somehow an implementation based on Identity and having the current web context information, pretty much in the same way that the Controller must be instantiated.

<s>Question is: how to get that data?</s>

A simpler solution, of course, would be to do it by hand in each Controller constructor, but there should be a more automatic and elegant way to solve this.

EDIT: After some more reasearch, thanks to the answer of Cuong Le, the question I had to ask was, in fact, "how to inject the UserManager from the current context?".

However, in order to decouple my services layer from MVC, I created an `IUserInfoProvider`, which provides access to the authenticated user data. The implementation based in Identity and the UserManager lies in the Web UI (MVC) project, so it has a `IPrincipal` as suggested by Cuong Le, and an `ApplicationUserManager`, all injected using Ninject.

The following interface abstract the user information from Identity and the UserManager.

```
public interface IUserInfoProvider<T>
{
    string GetUserId();
    T GetUserData();
}
```

Here is the implementation in the MVC project using Identity and UserManager.

```
public class IdentityUserInfoProvider : IUserInfoProvider<DatosEmpresa>
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly IPrincipal _user;

    public IdentityUserInfoProvider(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IPrincipal user)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _user = user;
    }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        return _user.Identity.GetUserId();
    }

    public DatosEmpresa GetUserData()
    {
        return _userManager.FindById(_user.Identity.GetUserId()).DatosEmpresa;
    }
}
```

And the Ninject configuration bit

```
kernel.Bind<IUserInfoProvider<DatosEmpresa>>().To<IdentityUserInfoProvider>();

kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>()
        .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User)
        .InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>())
        .InRequestScope();
```

Then I can use an `IUserInfoProvider` inside any service object and it gets the correct user.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what is the problem, but what I normally do is having all my controllers inherit from a "Base" class, and you can have there a property called UserId, which its' get method is to return the User.Identity.GetUserId()

Comment: I want my IDataService derived services to have access to the current Identity user id, without having to set it specifically from every controller that instantiates those services.

Comment: Can you access the HttpContext.Current.Session from those services?

check out this for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241298/getting-the-current-user-id-not-name-using-forms-authentication

Comment: Are you able to call your API directly?  eg write a winform app that calls the API?  If so, how are you handling authentication in those cases?  What's the IIS Authentication settings (Anonymous/Forms/Windows Authentication) on both the MVC and the WebAPI sites?

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution is you can put `IPrincipal` into NInject Container:

```
kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

So in your `ServiceBase` you can inject `IPrincipal` via either property or contructor, like this:

```
class ServiceBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IPrincipal User { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get information from this property.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I used your answer as a starting point for my solution. See the updated post for more details.